# Python find last occurence in a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with different IP's.

```
192.168.11.2
192.1268.11.3
192.168.11.3
192.168.11.3
192.168.11.2
192.168.11.5
```

This is my code until now. Where I print the IP and the occurence, but how can I found out when the last occurennce was for each of the IP's. Is it a simple way to do so?

```
liste = []

dit = {}
file = open('ip.txt','r')

file = file.readlines()

for line in file:
        liste.append(line.strip())

for element in liste:
        if element in dit:
                dit[element] +=1
        else:
                dit[element] = 1

for key,value in dit.items():
        print "%s occurs %s times, last occurence at line"  %(key,value)
```

Output:

```
192.1268.11.3 occurs 1 times, last occurence at line
192.168.11.3 occurs 2 times, last occurence at line
192.168.11.2 occurs 2 times, last occurence at line
192.168.11.5 occurs 1 times, last occurence at line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
liste = []

dit = {}
file = open('ip.txt','r')

file = file.readlines()

for line in file:
        liste.append(line.strip())

for i, element in enumerate(liste, 1):
        if element in dit:
                dit[element][0] += 1
                dit[element][1] =  i
        else:
                dit[element] = [1,i]

for key,value in dit.items():
        print "%s occurs %d times, last occurence at line %d" % (key, value[0], value[1])
```

Comment: The dictionary values are (immutable) tuples, so you can't add to the first element

Comment: Could you please comment the edited part ? I dont know what enumerate do.

Comment: @Iknowpython `enumerate()` returns enumerate object (just imagine list of tuples, each tuple has two values - element's index and the element itself). https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: What changes would I have to make to for instance print the line for first occurence? @konart

Comment: @Iknowpython Just don't increment the counter (comment `dit[element][1] =  i`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('ip.txt') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.read().splitlines()

    # Find last occurrence, count
    last_line = dict((ip, line_number) for line_number, ip in enumerate(lines, 1))
    ip_count = Counter(lines)

    # Print the stat, sorted by last occurrence
    for ip in sorted(last_line, key=lambda k: last_line[k]):
        print '{} occurs {} times, last occurence at line {}'.format(
            ip, ip_count[ip], last_line[ip])
```

## Discussion

- I use the `enumerate` function to generate line number (starting at line 1)
- With a sequence of (ip, line_number), it's easy to generate the dictionary `last_line` where the key is the IP address and the value is the last line it occurs
- To count the number of occurences, I use the `Counter` class--very simple
- If you want the report sorted by IP address, use `sorted(last_line)`
- This solution has a performance implication: it scans the list of IPs twice: once to calculate `last_line` and once to calculate `ip_count`. That means this solution might not be ideal if the file is large

Comment: why would you need to create a list of all the lines with `lines = input_file.read().splitlines()`?

Comment: As I stated in my post, the performance problem with my solution is I need to scan the list twice. I created the list so that I don't have to read the file twice.

Comment: You could just `file.seek(0)` and avoid reading all the content into memory.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I choose to read it once because (a) laziness, (b) processing in-memory list is faster than reading from file. As stated in my post, this solution is not ideal if the file is large; in which case, I will redesign my solution to read the file only once and not storing data in 3 separate structures: `lines`, `last_line`, and `ip_count`.

Answer (score 1):

```
last_line_occurrence = {}
for element, line_number in zip(liste, range(1, len(liste)+1)):
     if element in dit:
            dit[element] +=1
     else:
            dit[element] = 1
     last_line_occurrence[element] = line_number

for key,value in dit.items():
     print "%s occurs %s times, last occurence at line %s"  %(key,value, last_line_occurrence[key])
```

Comment: 1. Misspelled with 1 r: `last_line_occurence`. 2. You need `len(liste)+1`: `range(1, 5)` ==> `[1, 2, 3, 4]` which does not include 5.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done in a single pass without reading all the file into memory:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: {"ind":0,"count":0})

with open("in.txt") as f:
    for ind, line in enumerate(f,1):
        ip = line.rstrip()
        d[ip]["ind"] = ind
        d[ip]["count"]  += 1

for ip ,v in d.items():
    print("IP {}  appears {} time(s) and the last occurrence is at  line {}".format(ip,v["count"],v["ind"]))
```

Output:

```
IP 192.1268.11.3  appears 1 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 2
IP 192.168.11.3  appears 2 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 4
IP 192.168.11.2  appears 2 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 5
IP 192.168.11.5  appears 1 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 6
```

If you want the order the ip's are first encountered use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for ind, line in enumerate(f,1):
        ip = line.rstrip()
        od.setdefault(ip, {"ind": 0,"count":0})
        od[ip]["ind"] = ind
        od[ip]["count"] += 1

for ip ,v in od.items():
    print("IP {}  appears {} time(s) and the last occurrence is at  line {}".format(ip,v["count"],v["ind"]))
```

Output:

```
IP 192.168.11.2  appears 2 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 5
IP 192.1268.11.3  appears 1 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 2
IP 192.168.11.3  appears 2 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 4
IP 192.168.11.5  appears 1 time(s) and the last occurrence is at line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another dictionary. In this dictionary you store, for each line, the line number of the last occurrence and overwrite every time you find another occurrence. At the end, in this dictionary you will have, for each line, the line number of the last occurrence.

Obviously you will need to increment a counter for each read line in order to know the line you're reading right now.